# Reading a file, storing it in an arraylist, Iterating through the array, print data

Tags: java

I am writing a program that at its core will do 2 things:

1. Fill an ArrayList with the details of Students from a file that is read
2. Iterate through that array using user input to then fetch that specific students data and print it.

However I have 2 main questions:
1. Given the format of my file does the array actually get filled with data?
2. How do I find the specific student with all the data along with it?

This here is the format of the file(it's .txt):

ExampleName

ExampleSurname

01/01/2000

Male

ExampleAddress

ExampleYear

Maths, Science, English, R.E, Geography, History

and then another set of the data just like that.

To read this, this is my method:

```
//Method that will fill the array we created
    public static void fillStudentArray(ArrayList<Student> students) 
    {
        int size = 0;

        File file = new File("/Users/cool/Desktop/Student Details.txt");

        try 
        {
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner(file);

            while(readFile.hasNextLine()) 
            {
                firstName = readFile.next();
                surname = readFile.next();
                dob = readFile.next();
                gender = readFile.next();
                address = readFile.next();
                form = readFile.next();
                timetable = readFile.next();

                students.add(new Student(firstName, surname, dob, gender, address, form, timetable));

                size++;
                System.out.println(size);

                System.out.println("fillStudentArray in try section");
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Again I ask, would this method actually work to fill the array list if not why?

The second part is where I have more difficulty.
It is meant to read the user input, use it to iterate through the array and then print all of that students data, however, it doesn't work and as to why I'm not exactly sure.

This is the method I use:

```
//We can retrieve specific data from the array using this method
    public static void searchStudentData(ArrayList<Student> students, Scanner userInput, Student StudentData)
    {

        while(true) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the Student Name: ");
            String stringUserInput = userInput.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) 
            {   

                if(FirstName.equals(stringUserInput) || Surname.equals(stringUserInput)) 
                {
                    System.out.println(StudentData(FirstName, Surname, DoB, Gender, Address, Form, Timetable));
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Error, please try again.");
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
}
```

How would I make this method work? Where have I gone wrong and how can I fix it?

My full code:
https://pastebin.com/9jnykFe9

Comment: have you tried executing this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this even compile? In `if(FirstName.equals(stringUserInput) || Surname.equals(stringUserInput))` you assume that `FirstName` and `Surname` are variables but they are not. What you want to use is `students.get(i).firstName` since you want the first name of the current `Student` from your ArrayList. Then it should work.

Quick sidenotes here. In the upper part, the variable `size` can be omitted by `students.size`.

Hope this helps.